# WordPress - открывает пустую страницу ..wp-admin/post.php

Tags: wordpress

При добавлении новой страницы или обновлении существующей страницы из админки, WP перекидывает на страницу ..wp-admin/post.php. На этой странице ничего не отображается. Куда копать, подскажите? В консоли ошибок нет.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Скорее всего, неправильные rewrite в .htaccess

Comment: выглядят как стандартные для одиночного сайта WordPress без https. А снаружи сайт работает? В админке все в порядке, кроме добавления страницы? Плагины тогда все выключите и тему смените на стандартную, посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: кстати, по поводу плагинов. Role Scoper и WordPress Importer - установлены. При попытке установить list category posts - пишет: ошибка установки, но плагин сам устанавливается и активируется, но криво.

Comment: это уже другой вопрос, вы деактивируйте все что есть пока

Comment: все деактивировал, перевел на тему по умолчанию - все заработало

Comment: ну а теперь ищите виновника, включая назад по одному

Comment: как только переключаю тему - труба - ничего не работает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но хотелось бы найти ошибку. Не подскажете как тестировать темы? Что можно почитать по этой проблеме. Хочется знать истинную причину неполадок.

Comment: Отладчик - ничего нового не придумали. phpStorm + xDebug. Похоже, в теме используют add_rewrite_rule() и делают это с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь